# Debugging in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, debugging, error-handling

How can I turn on debugging and error log in WordPress? I am new to WordPress and would like to see how this could be done.

I set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in **wp-config.php** but this is not helping. Is there an error log file?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check your `php.ini` file for the location and name of your log file, the directive is named `error_log`.

Comment: Thanks, however, this only shows PHP errors, but it looks like there is an uncaught error by PHP, maybe logic or something, is there a way of using other error logs?

Answer (score 2):

A little late but in case this helps someone else, add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

All errors are then written to debug.log located within the wp-content folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "ErrorLog" and "CustomLog" location in your httpd.conf if you use apache.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem try to use the plugins like Issues Tracker or read the documentation wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress